# Is “I’ve boughten many vinyls” correct in its use of “boughten”?

Tags: dialects, parts-of-speech, past-participles, syntactic-analysis, descriptive-grammar

Per Merriam-Webster (https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/is-boughten-a-word) *boughten* is an adjective.

According to my non-native-English-speaking friend the sentence "I've boughten many vinyls" is not grammatically correct.   Is he right?

Adjectives (*boughten*) can be used to describe pronouns (many),  so although my sentence may be odd in today's times, is it grammatically correct?   If not, what rule is it breaking?

Comment: Ha! I came in here thinking this would be a discussion about the proper pluralization of "vinyl". For what it's worth, your sentence sounds weird to me, I'd instead say "I've purchased many albums" or maybe "I have a huge collection of vinyl."

Comment: Short - similar to others: A word does not HAVE to break any rules to either be wholly incorrect or so little used that it makes the user appear uneducated. |  Boughten is archaic or poetic at best. It would essentially never now be used in everyday speech and would cause 'raised eyebrows' almost anywhere.  In the above context "bought" can instead be used. As of 2008, bought is about 3,000 times more common than boughten in general English usage.  ...

Comment: ...  See [Ngram viewer - boughten](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boughten&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cboughten%3B%2Cc0)  =
 0.000001% ,  and [ngrams bought](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bought&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbought%3B%2Cc0) = 0.0035%

Comment: @RussellMcMahon That tells you nothing, really. Those of us who use those words do not use them to mean the same thing. There's good data that *boughten* is preferred as the adjective in some dialect communities.

Comment: @tchrist I. as you may well imagine, disagree, albeit not totally. I submit, from my lowly 2832 pedestal (my greater obsessions lying elsewhere), that "It tells you something.Really". I can believe that "boughten" may indeed be preferred in some dialectic communities, but, without further qualification on the part of the OP, I'd expect responses to assume the general community of "English as she is typically spoke all over the place", rather than select niches. ....

Comment: @tchrist ... That said, Any word used by  Ursula Le Guin, I'll fight for :-) - and at least defer to the usage by eg Samuel Taylor Coleridge, Robert Frost, L.M. Montgomery, and, of course, Chaucer :-).More common in Cornwall, and "the US", especially  Northern and North Midland, I'm told. 
As often [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/topicalwords/tw-bou1.htm) has a reasonable take on it.

Comment: "Adjectives (boughten) can be used to describe pronouns (many)" Do you have any example of an adjective modifying a pronoun? I agree with RBZ's answer below that "many" needs to come before "broughten".

Comment: @curiousdannii it's 'baughten' Dannnii not "broughten'. Although, that sounds just as familiar in some strange way.

Comment: @Abstractioniseverything. Oops yes, although b**o**ughten, not b**a**ughten!

Comment: Lol too funny! And tuchet'. I may have misspelled that also...

Comment: I think if you want to "win the bet" you should need at least 2 "dialectic" speakers, other than yourself, to agree the sentence is **not strange** in any way.  (Of course your friend would have to agree to it, but it does sound like this is narrow enough only others of your dialect can really weigh in)

Comment: Do you really want to ask about the adjectival form, or about the verb form? You can tell by substituting a different word for *boughten*: which fits better in your sentence where you currently have *boughten*, *old* ("I've **old** many vinyls") or *purchased* ("I've **purchased** many vinyls")? If the first is more like your sentence, you do have an adjective, but we would normally re-order the adjectives to "*many boughten*" instead of "*boughten many*". If the second substitution is closer to your meaning, then you're talking about a form of the *verb*, not an adjective.

Comment: Ah, you mention it is supposed to be an adjective, but it looks like a verb in that sentence - especially since the closest association would be the verb "to buy".  It might help to put "many" before "boughten" if you're going to use it as an adjective - even that looks a bit odd and would be clearer without the contraction ("I have many" instead of "I've many"), but I think it may break no rules.

Comment: Say, "I have many boughten vinyl albums", if you want to say your albums are bought, not stolen or loaned.  I'm familiar with this usage, although it's uncommon.

Comment: _Many_ is not a pronoun in your sentence—it’s a determiner. And adjectives can modify neither pronouns nor determiners. @Abstraction Yes, it’s _touché_, not _*tuchet’_. And _broughten_ probably sounds familiar from the quote “Oh, it’s already been broughten!” popularised by _Not Another Teen Movie_.

Comment: The MN article is: completely stupid.  The sentence "boughten is not a word" can only be described as wholly correct.  if you look up boughten in an actual dictionary (ie, the OED) it is marked: archaic.  End of story.  Questions like this cause incredible confusion on this site.  **At best** this should have been a question on ELL, and the answer would have been "no it's not a word".

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Of ***boughten*** the OED writes:

> **boughten**, *ppl. a.* [irreg. f. **bought** *ppl. a.* by assimilation to *foughten*] = **bought** *ppl. a.* used *poet.* for the sake of metre, otherwise only *dial.* and in U.S. in application to purchased as opposed to home-made articles.

Under the OED’s entry for *buy*, in the section on that verb’s inflections and their historical spellings, at no point does anything even vaguely like *boughten* ever enter the picture for that verb’s past participle.

In Bryan Garner’s *Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style* (2000), he writes on page 51:

> The form *boughten* (= store-bought as opposed to home-made) is an archaic past-participial adjective formed on the analogy of words such as *broken, driven,* and *frozen*. It still occurs in dialectal speech in the North and Northeast (in the sense “store-bought”), but not elsewhere.  E.g.: “In those days any *boughten* [read *store-bought*] cookie we would see in Maine was made by the Loose-Wiles Biscuit Company, which had a huge brick factory near the railroad tracks in Boston’s North End” (*Christian Science Monitor*).

In Standard English *boughten* is never a past participle the way you have used it here. It is at most only ever a participial adjective, either in dialect speech or else in the United States for things you have purchased rather than made yourself.

In those dialects that still use it, *boughten* is usually just an adjective, not a past participle. It’s one of those oddities of a verb that presents  a four-fold paradigm: the base verb, past tense, past participle, and then a distinct participial adjective ending in *-en* not seen in the past participle.

In this way it works somewhat like the verb *drink* works:

- drink, drank, drunk, **drunken**
- buy, bought, bought, **boughten**

So as adjectives we can say a *drunken sailor* or a *store-boughten item*, but those are still just *have drunk* and *have bought* when past participles.

Another example of this model can be found in U.K. speakers who wouldn’t be caught dead using *gotten* as a past participle even in the situations where North American speakers would use it, and yet those same U.K. speakers find nothing amiss with using it as a participial adjective in *only-begotten son*.

As the OED notes, this old participial adjective form of *boughten* is now reduced to dialects only or in the U.S. for a particular application. For example, it can still be heard in Cornwall and various places around the American Midwest.

But since Standard English isn’t so fond of it, if it is not already in your dialect, you should not use it, especially in formal writing. If you’re writing dialogue or just chewing the fat with friends, don’t worry about it.

My own rural dialect from the southeastern corner of Wisconsin retains *boughten* items, and I do use it in that fashion, but I don’t enjoy constantly having to justify this to people whose dialect lacks it and who are unaware of the word’s existence let alone its history.

## On Correctness

In comments, the asker repeats the question about whether *have boughten* is “correct”, and whether there exists some definitive grammatical “rule” providing a simple yes or no answer respectively supporting or disputing the “correctness” of the *have boughten* construction.

If you’re a kindergarten teacher guiding your young charges into a normalized form of Standard English, then you will want to suggest to them that they not say that. Prescriptive normalization can have its place, and some would argue that this is one of them.

However, from a linguist’s perspective, the question doesn’t really make much sense. That’s because it presupposes tacit acceptance of the proposition that “correct” is even a thing, and moreover that it is a thing which is either black or white. That’s not how linguists describe the language they observe. It’s something of a category error that is apt to puzzle them; it’s the wrong question to ask them because it doesn’t make sense given how they look at language.

So-called grammatical “rules” are just codifications of collected observations about how real people actually speak. So *grammatical* just means “sounds ok to a native speaker”, while *ungrammatical* just means “doesn’t sound ok to a native speaker” — nothing more and nothing less. There can be infinitely many gradations of grey acceptability stretching between those two black-and-white fenceposts of yes and no.

The bottom line is that Standard English does not gladly admit *have boughten*, but various dialects do. If that’s your dialect, then so be it, but be warned that you may suffer the social opprobrium and stigmata commonly associated with dialect speech; check your wrists to make sure you’re still ok.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59693/discussion-on-answer-by-tchrist-is-ive-boughten-many-vinyls-correct-in-its-us).

Answer (score 16):

**It depends what you mean by “correct”.**  Different varieties of English — e.g. standard US English, or standard British English, or various regional dialects — work differently.  *He snuck round the back* is correct in US English, but not in British English, where it would be *He sneaked round the back.*  From a linguistic point of view, ‘correct’ means that some sentence follows the way that native speakers/writers of that variety of English would speak or write; ‘textbook’ rules are just careful descriptions of how some variety works — typically, formal standard US or British English.  In popular use, ‘correct’ is often used to mean ‘correct in formal standard US or British English’ — but this is rather unfortunate, because (among other reasons) it often leads to non-standard dialects and their speakers getting stigmatised as wrong, ignorant, simplistic, and so on.

**In standard English (either US or British), the sentence is not correct, because *boughten* is not a word of standard English at all.**  This is probably what your non-native speaker friend means.

In standard English, the past participle of *buy* is just *bought*, so it should be *I’ve bought many vinyls.*

**In some regional varieties of English, it is perfectly correct.**  This is presumably what you mean.

In some dialects, the word *boughten* is the past participle of *buy*, analogous to *eaten*, the past participle of *eat*.  So since you would indeed say *I’ve eaten many vinyls* (not a recommended diet, but certainly grammatically correct), you would similarly say *I’ve boughten many vinyls*.

In other dialects, though, *boughten* exists but is only used as an adjective, not a participle — analogously to *drunken*, with which you can say *a drunken man* but not **I have drunken many beers*.  So in these dialects, your example sentence is not correct.

Either way: if you are a native English speaker and it sounds right to you, or if you heard this sentence from a native English speaker and it wasn’t a slip of the tongue because they’d drunken too many beers, then yes, it’s almost certainly correct at least in the regional/subcultural variety of English that you/they learned to speak in.

Comment: *"because they’d drunken too many beers"* - thanks for the laugh!

Comment: You say its not a word.  But it is.  Check merriam webster!  And google!

Comment: @Meep: that sentence starts with a qualifier: "In standard English". It says "In standard English, there is no such word as 'boughten' ". Everyone has their own viewpoint about what qualifies as standard English. You shouldn't make bets about things that you can't define objectively.

Comment: @Meep, the online Merriam-Webster says that _boughten_ is "chiefly dialectal".

Comment: @Meep: I didn’t mean to say it’s not a word at all — have edited to clarify.  I just meant that it’s not a word of *standard* English — and dictionaries (Merriam-Webster and the OED) confirm this, marking it as dialectal/regional.  It’s a perfectly cromulent word for plenty of people, and I don’t mean to disrespect that at all.

Comment: +1 One teeny, tiny quibble...since we're talking about dialectal differences...a native AmE speaker in the US would almost certainly say "he snuck ***a**round* the back."

Comment: @1006a Actually, that would sound odd compared to 'round. I'd probably drop the 'the' as well: he snuck round back.

Comment: @DCShannon Hmm, maybe it's regional. I'm from the Midwest, with a decade spent in California, and *'round* sounds vehdy vehdy British to me. I find many examples of "snuck around the back" both online generally and in Google books, many fewer for "snuck round the back", and fewer still with "snuck round back". The alleged results in Books are 1,340 : 163 : 3, and in the interweb generally 454,000 : 5,990 : 894. Of course those are not all "real" results, but the ratios are probably still informative.

Answer (score 8):

Your link includes the following:

> Boughten is also used in some dialects as a past participle of buy. The past participle of buy (and also the simple past tense form) in Standard English is bought. We say "I will buy some cookies soon," and later "I have bought the cookies." But boughten is also used by some: "**I have boughten the cookies**" (emphasis mine).

Notice it says "used by some." In this case, "some"  probably means .0005%  of the population. I've never used the word *boughten*. It's grammatical for those whom it's grammatical.

Comment: I've never used *boughten* as a past participle, but certainly it’s a common enough adjective in Wisconsin and Minnesota.

Comment: This book says there is a 57:2 ratio of boughten:bought in North-East US.  So >98% boughten. https://books.google.com/books?id=tbdZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22boughten%22&dq=%22boughten%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqw8nx_4XUAhWIKyYKHRjFDD44ChDoAQhTMAk

Comment: @DavePhD Excellent reference! It’s hard to pretend that a catsup-like 57:2 ratio is actually a 1:2000 ratio. :)

Comment: @tchrist and definitely not 1:200,000. :)

Comment: I've never even heard of it.

Comment: @Casey [Plenty more where these came from](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22boughten%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en#q=%22boughten%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=50).

Answer (score 7):

As others have noted, "boughten" can be used as a verb (in some dialects) and an adjective.

The OP wants to know if the sentence is correct with respect to its use as an adjective, and to that I would have to say no.

Quite correctly, the OP states that an adjective can be used to describe a pronoun, and that "many" can be used as a pronoun. However, it can also be an adjective or, as in this particular example, a determiner.

Determiners (e.g. a, the, some, other) precede adjectives in a noun phrase, so "I've many boughten vinyls" becomes the correct ordering of the sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Others have pointed out that the usage of *boughten* is common in some regional dialects, but that its usage is uncommon elsewhere. Here is some more data:

According to google ngram viewer, usage of *boughten* peaked around 1939. Of Google's very large sample of published material in 2007, bought was used 99.958% of the time versus 0.042% for *boughten* (a ratio of about 2,388 to 1). That's not uncommon enough for me to have never heard of it, but it is uncommon enough that I would never use it.

Disclaimer: This data comes from published books, and does not count usage in formal or informal speech.

Source: [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boughten%2C+bought&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cboughten%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bboughten%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBoughten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cbought%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbought%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBought%3B%2Cc0)